# is it legal to read the code of github copilot?

Tags: copyright, licensing, legal-terms, terms-of-service, trade-secret

I have already downloaded the extension from the Visual Studio Market place in the .VSIX file. and unzipped it ,Now I'm confused. What are these .wasm files and I tried to open the extension.js but it is not to get formatted. do you know how I can format it ? I am trying to understand how the github copilot works and what contents does it send to servers. I was asking someone on how to extract all this info but his reply was "Since I am not sure if what you are planning is even legal and not breaking any TOS, i will be providing no further support regarding this question."

So, can someone tell me if it is legal to read the code of github copilot ? Or it is reverse engineering of trade secret?